# Labview : 1D array sorting after removing minus numbers and duplicates

Tags: arrays, sorting, labview

I have one number array like below picture.

[image]

I'd like to remove whole minus numbers and duplicate numbers, and sort the array in ascending order, like below.

[image]

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job :

- Sort the array
- Find 0 and cut the array
- Substract rotated array to find doubles (=0)
- remove doubles

[image: Block Diagram]

[image: Front Panel]

Answer (score 1):

Unless there was a real efficiency need, I'd shoot for simplicity and readability:

1. Sort the array
2. Feed it into a for loop with a conditional concatenation terminal

   1. Use a feedback node to get the last value
   2. If this value is >0 and != to the last value, send true to the concatenation terminal.

You could always AND the >0 and != tests together and wire that directly to the concatenation terminal.

The output array from the for loop will be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I like Vivien's use of `Threshold 1D Array` and `Array Subset` to remove the negative values, but the rotate and subtract before removing zeroes seems unnecessarily complex. Here's a solution with a `For` loop, shift register and conditional indexing:

[image: LabVIEW 2014 VI snippet (drag and drop on the VI block diagram)]

Note that we have to initialise the shift register with something, or it would remember data from the previous run, giving unwanted behaviour (the same would be true of a feedback node) - so we make sure that the first array element will always be included by ensuring that the initialisation value is not equal to the first element.